# PasteSpecial(): wdPasteOLEObject and wdInLine Enumerations

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, enumeration

I have written code in Excel VBA and am currently trying to convert it to vb.NET on VS 2017.

I want to copy a table in Excel, and paste it into a Word document and also keep a live link between them so that any changes in the Excel table will be transferred to the table pasted in the Word document. I managed this in Excel VBA, however vb.NET does not recognise `DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject` and also `Placement:=wdInLine`, saying they are not declared.

The following is a sample from my code:

```
excelApp = New Excel.Application
excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(SurveyFormLoc)
excelApp.Visible = True

With excelApp
    .Sheets("Site Details").Select 
    .Range("B2:I11").Copy()
End With

wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(DesignReportLoc)

With wdDoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "INSERT FROM SURVEY FORM"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute()
    .Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0               
End With

wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial(Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
```

Does anybody know what the vb.NET equivalent is to do this?

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] to enahnce the help you get.  Things like A Good Title and Formatting Your code to look like code are important as well as asking a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `wdPasteOLEObject` with the number 0.

Replace `wdInLine` with the number 0 also.

[PasteDataType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdpastedatatype-enumeration-word)

[Placement Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdoleplacement-enumeration-word)

You could also define the `Enumeration` yourself if you want to preserve the readability:

```
Enum WdOLEPlacement 
  wdFloatOverText = 1
  wdInLine = 0 
End Enum

Enum WdPasteDataType 
  wdPasteBitmap = 4 
  wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap = 5    
  wdPasteEnhancedMetafile = 9   
  wdPasteHTML = 10  
  wdPasteHyperlink = 7  
  wdPasteMetafilePicture = 3    
  wdPasteOLEObject = 0  
  wdPasteRTF = 1    
  wdPasteShape = 8  
  wdPasteText = 2   
End Enum
```

And in your code, reference like this:

```
DataType:=WdPasteDataType.wdPasteOLEObject 
Placement:=WdOLEPlacement.wdInLine
```

If you run into undefined `Enumerations` again, you can just go to google and paste the thing you want to look up and include the word `Enum` and it will usually be the first result.

Comment: Thank you so much, the advice about googling enumerations has helped me solve a couple more problems also. 

However, now when I run the code, I get the error message 'This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid.', when it tries to paste the copied range into the Word Doc.

Have you any idea why the .Copy() doesn't appear to be working?

Thank you

Comment: If the clipboard is empty, I would consider this a separate question. You may want to isolate the problem and ask a new question.